# ext4 separate files into subdirectories VS one big directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

Will organizing files into subfolders enhance read access performance on an ext4 filesystem compared to storing them all in a single large directory?

We currently have a single large directory containing 600K files (3-10 MB each). Would there be a performance improvement if we organize these files into subfolders, with each subfolder containing 5K files?

Could you please propose some tools to perform such kind of benchmarks?

As an additional information, we uses these files by reading them by full path and writing new files into the directory. Also, newly created files we read more often than older ones

Comment: It's not a coincidence that automatically created cache directories often use 256 subdirectories with a further 256 subdirectories in each. If not 256, some other round number, and sometimes only one sub-level of directories, and sometimes up to three, depending on the mood of the developer. See e.g. the `.git/objects` directory in any Git repository, or your browser's cache directory structure.

Comment: Aside from any performance hit, consider debugging. If you have several million files in a directory it is inevitably going to be harder to trawl through them by hand than if you've got just a few hundred (or thousand) files to consider. Don't forget to consider how you're going to track down a problem when it occurs

Comment: We don't enumerate these files, we store the path for each file in the database and access files by this path. There are three operations we do with our storage - read files by full path, create new files and delete some files by full path. We just want to know in such usage as we do will we have any possible issues when we increase number of files from 600K till 1M?

Answer (score 2):

> 3-10 MB each

The file size doesn't matter.

> Will organizing files into subfolders enhance read access performance on an ext4 filesystem compared to storing them all in a single large directory?

Logically, that depends on what you mean with "performance": If you need to list *all* files, then putting them in subdirectories is worse. If you know which subdirectory to look into, and only need to list that then, that might be faster.

The interesting case is when you just need to access files by name, never to get a directory listing:

> We currently have a single large directory containing 600K files (3-10 MB each). Would there be a performance improvement if we organize these files into subfolders, with each subfolder containing 5K files?

Again, depends on your usage pattern! It looks like you're rarely listing the directory, so the differences won't be large.

Getting a file from a directory works roughly like this:

1. The path is decomposed into components (`/path/to/file` -> `path`, `to`, `file`)
2. for each, the containing directory's index needs to be asked (so, to be able to look into `to`, you need to look up `to` in `path`'s index; to get `file`, you need to look up `file` in `to`'s index, for which you first need to have looked up `to` in `path`.

Obviously, the deeper your paths, the more lookups, which takes some time.

The question is: Does looking up an entry from an `N`-files index take more time than doing two consecutive lookups on `sqrt(N)` indices? (so, that's the case where you take your `N` files, and put them into `sqrt(N)` directories, with `sqrt(N)` entries each.)

And the answer is: no. Ext4 uses [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) indices, meaning that the optimized implementation of directory entry lookup takes `log[N]` time in the first case, and `2·log[sqrt(N)] = 2·log[N^(1/2)] = 2·(1/2)·log[N] = log[N]` asymptotically.

Of course, looking through *one* data structure is usually *much* preferable in terms of data locality, especially if that guarantees you never have to go back to storage to read the "deeper" directory's index. So, the single large directory will win against the many smaller ones in terms of lookup time.

Will that matter much? I doubt it. 600,000 files isn't very many.

**However**, the situation is different if your application is smart: if you open all the directory descriptors once only (for later usage with `openat`), and keep their structure around in your application, then of course you *would* benefit from only having to look into smaller indices. Note that if you know you'll read a file again pretty certainly, it might be smart to keep the file descriptor open and store it in an internal table of sorts for some time. The *significant* part of time spent is probably not on directory lookups – but on the context switches that happen when you `open` and `close` a file.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. As I mentioned, we do not perform directory listing, only read/delete/create files by full path. All information about files we store into a database, where all needed listing and search we do. So, to clarify, according to our usage we can have even 1M files in one directory without any imacts, right?

Comment: @YevgeniyLogachev so, it would work. And honestly, thinking about how to optimize it now would probably be premature optimization – use something like `perf` or `bpftrace` to figure out how long things like `open` and `close` actually take with a million files in a directory, before you try to be smarter than an operating system. (I mean, Artem is worried about "more than a few hundred files". He might be using an Amiga, but I'd rather assume he has not actually benchmarked this yet. Is "a few hundred" the point where I'm sure it doesn't matter? A few thousand? A few million? I don't know;

Comment: I would want to profile a mockup of my usage pattern really quickly before I start investing development time.) It's certain that if your application keeps a table in memory that says which file is in which subdirectory, as explained, you'd open these directories (using something like `int dir_fd = open("/path/to/directory", O_PATH);`) and keep the resulting directory file descriptors in memory for later usage with `openat(dir_fd, "filename.data",…);`. This *will* skip a subdirectory lookup in the kernel, very nicely. But, again, whether or not you really need that optimization: not clear!

Answer (score 1):

It's **extremely** ill-advised to have more than a few hundred files in a single directory.

- A file system error due to e.g. an outage could render *all* the files inaccessible temporarily or permanently.
- Filesystem cache will be premantly polluted by all the entries.
- Multiple operations will take forever to complete due to a massive amount of data and kernel work to generate all the entries including listing and search operations.

I'm not even sure your use case warrants FS storage. You probably could consider a database, including NoSQL.

Comment: I agree with some things here, with others I strongly disagree: **1. point** your file system error is successfully prevented by the WAL-structured committing of metadata on modern file system (that's why most things call themselves "journaling" these days!). Also, if you're actually concerned about such errors, then having more chances to corrupt a subdirectory entry rather than just individual file entries is not inherently a benefit to stability. **2. point**: The file system cache will depend on the number of files you cache, not how they are organized.

Comment: **3. point**: depends, see the wholeness of my answer showing that for listing, what you claim is wrong.